# How can I updated just a dropdown list using knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

My solution use template and component approach. I have a custom generic dropdown in ui and I use a modal window with a textbox input incide another template and component. I want to enter my new item value in the textbox zone. And after I need to add ths new item refresh the dowpdown list

my view

```
<dropdown params="{options: $component.displayImages, 
                    value: $component.selected.displayImage, 
                    optionsText: 'label', 
                    optionsCaption: 'Sélectionner une image ...',
                    enabled:$component.displayImageEnabled(), 
                    medium: $root.isTemplateMode(), 
                    large: !$root.isTemplateMode()}"></dropdown>
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer this we need to know what the dropdown component does.

But I will try to answer the query based on the information from the question.

You have a select drop down whose value needs to updated based on a back end viewmodel array.

You can refer the following code

HTML

```
<select>
<!-- ko foreach :availablePersons -->
 <option data-bind="text:$data.value"></option>
 <!--/ko-->
</select>

 <input type="text" data-bind="value: newPerson"></input>
 <input type="button" value="Add" data-bind="click:addPerson"></input>
```

View Model :

```
// Overall viewmodel for this screen, along with initial state
function SelectionModel() {
    var self = this;

self.addPerson=function(){
self.availablePersons.push({key:self.newPerson(), value:self.newPerson()});
self.newPerson("");
}

    self.newPerson = ko.observable("");
    // Non-editable catalog data - would come from the server
    self.availablePersons = ko.observableArray([
        { key: 1, value: "Jerin" },
        { key: 2, value: "Arjun" },
    ]);    

}

ko.applyBindings(new SelectionModel());
```

JS Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/07jerin/Lzpftc82/